# Регулярка: необязательные символы, перед квантификатором ".+"

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Здравствуйте, есть список строк:

```
"number: что угодно"
"что угодно 2"
"number: что угодно 3"
```

Нужно именно регуляркой получить такой результат:

```
"что угодно"
"что угодно 2"
"что угодно 3"
```

Такой пример мне не помогает:

```
preg_match('/:?\s*(.+)/', 'number: что угодно', $matches)
```

Answer (score 3):

```
preg_match('/^(?:.*:)?\s*(.+)/', 'number что угодно', $matches);
```

Мы объявляем необязательными все символы от начала строки до двоеточия, таким образом, когда двоеточие есть выделяется строка после него, а когда двоеточия нет, то не ожидаем вообще ни одного символа

Answer (score 2):

Как вариант: в группе без обратной связи сначала попробовать перебрать все символы до двоеточия, само двоеточие и идущие за ним не обязательные пробелы (возможно стоит заменить `\s` на `\x20`), а потом уже выбрать то что вам нужно:

```
/(?:.*?:\s*)?(.+)/
```

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте `.*?(что угодно .*)`. Должно помочь.

Comment: Звездочки сожрало. Помле точек - звездочка

Comment: Вернул звёздочки.

Comment: Спасибо, я с планшета,  тут неудобно разметку делать.

Answer (score 0):

```
$newSubject = preg_replace("#^(?:.+:)?\s*(.+)\s*$#", "$1", $subject);
```

если присутствуют, то все всимволы не являющиеся двоеточием отсекаются в пассивной группе `(?:)`, также, отсекаются все символы, не входящие в группу между предполагаемыми пробелами. на выходе имеем только строку, попавшую в группу, на которую и изменяется исходная строка

пример:

```
$ cat example.php
<?php
foreach ([
    "number: что угодно",
    "что угодно 2",
    "number: что угодно 3"
] as $subject) {
    $newSubject = preg_replace("#^(?:.+:)?\s*(.+)\s*$#", "$1", $subject);
    echo "$newSubject\n";
}
$ php example.php
что угодно
что угодно 2
что угодно 3
```

Answer (score -1):

```
preg_match('/^(?:\s*number:\s*)?\s*(.+)$/', 'number: что угодно', $matches);
```

Comment: напишите более развёрнуто

Comment: Пожалуйста, постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Уверен, автор вопроса был бы благодарен за ваш экспертный комментарий к приведенному выше коду.